# Почему при добавлении проекта на github, при его скачивании приходится скачивать react, это нормальная практика?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs, github

Я хочу отправить тестовое задание hr, но вот этот момент меня беспокоит, потому что нельзя сразу скачать и ввести команду npm start. Это нормальная практика каждый раз писать npm install react react-dom на каждый новый скачанный проект. Я недавно скачивал для разбора тоже чей то код и пришлось вводить те же команды что выше перечислил. Или нужно делать eject или еще что то? Спасибо!

Comment: нормальная практика писать просто npm install - и ставить сразу все нужные зависимости.

Comment: ооооооооооооооооооооооооооу. Теперь все сомнения ушли прочь. Я так понял для этого Json файл и нужен

Comment: да, в package.json как раз и указывается что нужно для работы

Comment: более того - package.lock.json или yarn.lock (или как там они называются) тоже хранят

Comment: @rtn2020, https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/2.4.php